# When should we close the proxy when calling WCF service asynchronously using EAP

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have a client that is using EAP(Event-based Asynchronous Programming) to call WCF service asynchronously.

But when I try to close the client proxy after calling the service I see that client hangs up and it works in a synchronous manner.

When I don't close the client proxy after calling the service the call works fine in asynchronous manner.

Do I need to close the proxy in some different way when using EAP ?

I need to process large number of concurrent requests asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, we do not need to close the client connection because the server automatically closes the connection. 
This depends on the following parameters. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
Besides, I suggest you enable the concurrency on the server side.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode?view=netframework-4.8
Feel free to let me know If there is anything I can help with.